# Average of iterative sum of arrays with nan elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am summing arrays containing `nan` values by using:

```
for i in range(whatever):
    a = *something different at each cycle*
    b = np.nansum([b, a],axis=0)

#now calculate the average of b elements avoiding nan counts
```

(`b` and `a` being of the same size).
Now, as you can see, this is iterative, adding the elements to create at the end one single sum-array.

At the end, I would like to calculate the average for each of the elements of the final `b` array, excluding the `nan` elements from the count, of course.

All the other discussions I found only take in account two arrays, and the average of their elements is obtained by using [nanmean](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html), but this is not possible here, I think.

Possibly, I could also change the way to sum the elements, if `nansum` is not the best way, but this is how I did it until now.

So, is there a simple way to obtain the final average excluding `nan` elements from the count?

EDIT: the iteration is made several times, not just one, using `a` array (in the example) changing in each cycle. This is why I am not able to use the same solution as in the linked question

Comment: In that case the OP do not sum iteratively. Or, I don't know how to reduce the two cases to the same solution.

Comment: You can't simply keep track of the number of NaNs in a, take the sum of b after the loop and divide by the total number of non-NaN elements (`len(whatever) * a.size - totalNaNs`)?

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of the number of non-`nan` elements yourself

```
n = np.zeros(*shape of a*)
for i in range(whatever):
    a = *something different at each cycle*
    b = np.nansum([b, a],axis=0)
    n = np.sum([n, np.invert(np.isnan(a))],axis=0)

avg = b/n
```

Comment: this can not work. This returns a number, while I need an array of the summation of nan for each element position.

Comment: You are right, I had misinterpreted what you were trying to do. I've updated my answer to do what you want.